# Replacing Framing Question

Tags: framing, replacement

I was replacing some water damaged siding (see first pic) and noticed that the bottom 2x4 was a little rotted as well (see second pic). It doesn't appear to be load bearing. Do I need to replace the full board, or can I cut out the bad and connect it? Lastly what wood would I use to replace this with regular 2x4 (white wood) or would I use weather treated, or something else
[image: Bad Siding]
[image: Bad Board]
[image: Full Picture]

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the photo, that rot seems superficial and as long as you prevent future water infiltration it may be fine to leave it.

I would take a small nail and see how deep the rot is at several different points. Unless it is severe (i.e., maybe 1/3 or more through the wood?) it is probably OK to leave it.

Answer (score 0):

The 2x4 is part of your roof trusses and it is supporting some of the roof load. Since it is sitting on the wall it would be ok to replace just the rotten section. Make sure it is fasten to the wall on either side of the cut before cutting.  I would add a backer 2x4 over the splices.  You could use treated lumber for extra protection in case of another leak but a regular 2x4 will be fine if the leak is fixed.